# Problem expanding Ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, gparted

I have 50 GBs of unallocated space on my hard drive and I want to expand my Ubuntu partition to fill that space; however, when I run gparted in a live version of Ubuntu and turn the swap off, it only allows my to expand my Windows partition into the free space but won't let me do the same with the Ubuntu partition. Any idea as to how I can fix this?

Comment: We need to know the layout of your partitions.

Answer (score 0):

To expand your Ubuntu partition you will need to boot from a USB or CD, unmount the HDD ubuntu partition and resize it using gparted.  Create the USB, boot from it, open a terminal and load gparted

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then you can resize the ubuntu partition of the HDD.

I'm updating this slightly - The new space that you intend to use must be contiguous with the partition that you intend to expand

Comment: The OP has already said he has tried that. :)

Comment: I read it to indicate that he had tried that from his hard disk installation of Ubuntu - I may well be mistaken!

Comment: He says "live version." I don't see any reason to think he doesn't mean the live media.